# Why my PHP mysql code accepting customer orders with zero products in the cart?

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I have developed an online shopping website with PHP and mysql. When a customer placing an order, at first I am checking if there is any product in his cart. If there's no product, he cannot place order and show him a message that his cart is empty and redirect him to the home page.
But today someone somehow managed to place an order without a single product in his cart. How this can be possible? Is this possible that code may sometimes fail to execute  accurately? If not, how come it happened in my case?

I am posting lines of my code I have used in saving a customer order.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$cutomer_id=$_SESSION['customer_id'];
$customer_address=$_POST['delivery_address'];
$customer_name=$_POST['customer_name'];
$session_id= session_id();

//IF CART EMPTY THEN REJECT ORDER
$strSql= "select * from cart where session_id='" .$session_id."'";

    $result= mysqli_query ($con,$strSql);
    //if nothing found in cart then opt out
    $count_prods = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                            if($count_prods==0){

                            echo "Your cart is empty";
                            exit;
                            }
//UPDATE THE DELIVERY ADDRESS OF THE CUSTOMER
$update_address="UPDATE user_info SET address1='$customer_address', first_name='$customer_name' WHERE user_id='$cutomer_id'";

$success= mysqli_query($con,$update_address);

//making order number
$strsql2="SELECT NEXTval('order_number_producer') as order_number";
    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$strsql2);
    $got_it=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $order_number=$got_it['order_number'];

//first insert into new orders

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Delhi");
$orderTime=date("d-m-Y h:i:s A");

$strsql3="INSERT INTO new_order (order_number, customer_id, order_status,delivery_date, delivery_time,order_time) VALUES ('$order_number','$cutomer_id','processing','$delivery_date','$delivery_time','$orderTime')";
$successfull= mysqli_query($con,$strsql3);

//Now insert order details into order_details table

$strSql= "select * from cart where session_id='" .$session_id."'";

    $result= mysqli_query($con,$strSql);
    while ($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $p_id       =$rows['p_id'];
    $qty    = $rows['qty'];
    $price  = $rows['price'];


$strsqlOrderDetails="INSERT INTO order_details(order_number, product_id, qty, price) VALUES ('$order_number','$p_id','$qty','$price')";
    $done= mysqli_query($con,$strsqlOrderDetails);

}

//New order created, ordered products inserted...NOW CLEAR THE CART OF   CUSTOMER
$clearcart=$strSql= "delete from cart where session_id='" .$session_id."'";

    $cleared= mysqli_query($con,$clearcart);
echo "Order submitted. Your order number is # $order_number";

}
?>
```

Comment: what data was in fields (product_id, qty, price) ? are they were empty?

Comment: Yes @Chudilka, it was empty. And unfortunately my code allowed the customer to proceed with the order even his cart did not have any product. I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be the infamous button double click problem. Looks like the order went through on the first click and the cart was emptied as a result.

Then with the second click (in the double click) the order was not found?

Perhaps try to simulate this behaviour by double clicking on the button and if this is the culprit, add some javascript to prevent the double click of the button.

Comment: Only one order has been placed by this customer, not two. And that is empty (without any product). order_number has been created, then the order_number and customer details has been inserted into NEW_ORDER table as directed in the code. But nothing inserted in the ORDER_DETAILS table against this order number as there was no product in the cart. So how this order bypassed the 'check if there is any item in the cart' code block?